# Php - MySql Not fetching datas from tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php sql script to display datas in datatable.
It displays the details of the children from tbl_child and fetch the latest course from the table_class and both the table are connected to l.childfkey=c.childpid.

here is the problem. the following script work well if i place

**$select = $pdo->prepare(" select   *  from tbl_child c .......................... )**

but i dont need all the fields so if i mention only some fields it wont show the records from tbl_class.

Here is the script which is not fetching from tbl_class

```
$select = $pdo->prepare(" select 
                   childpid,
                   child_name,
                   child_surname,
                   child_birth,
                   child_age,
                                        
                   from tbl_child c 
                   
                   LEFT JOIN (SELECT classpid,childfkey,class_courseyear,class_course FROM tbl_class  where classpid IN (
                   
                    SELECT MAX(classpid)
                    FROM tbl_class 
                    GROUP BY childfkey
                   
                   
                   ))l ON l.childfkey=c.childpid
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Go inform yourself how to get error messages from the database.

Comment: In this case, it is probably just the extra comma after your last column name, before `from tbl_child c`, that causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you use an alias in your child table **tbl_child c** but in the above, you select your column without the alias **c**.

Select column with the alias like:-

> c.childpid, c.child_name

Thanks